# Eloquent way of defining a one-to-one relationship using intermediate table to avoid foreign key cycle

Tags: php, laravel, database-design, eloquent, model

Laravel rookie here. I've got **titles** and **reviews**. A title can have many reviews, a review belongs to a title.

So far, my tables look unsurprisingly as follows:

```
titles:
  - id (pk)
  ...

reviews:
  - id (pk)
  - title_id (fk)
  ...
```

Now, I want a title to have **zero or one** (so-called) top reviews.

My first instinct was to add a nullable `top_review_id` column to the `titles` table, but I wanted to avoid a cycle of foreign keys. So instead, I created a third table called `top_reviews` as follows:

```
top_reviews:
  - id
  - title_id (fk, unique)
  - review_id (fk, unique)
```

That way a title is guaranteed to have at most one top review and a review cannot be the top review for multiple titles. (I do realise that it is still possible to have a top review entry where the review actually belongs to a different title, but that's okay.)

**My question is how do I wire that up cleanly in Laravel (7.x) ideally using Eloquent ORM relationships and following the framework's best practices?**

So far I've got this:

```php
class Title extends Model {
    public function reviews() { return $this->hasMany(Review::class); }
    public function topReview() { /* ??? */ }
}

class Review extends Model {
    public function title() { return $this->belongsTo(Title::class); }
}
```

I've considered the following:

- I could manually build something ugly like `return Review::find(DB::table('top_reviews')->select('review_id')->where('title_id', $this->id)->get());`, but I suspect there is a nicer Laravelesque way for these trivial relationships.
- Simply using `hasOne()` doesn't seem to be the solution either since it will assume a different table name (namely `reviews` instead of `top_reviews`) and there is no way to specify a custom table.
- Defining a model `TopReview` seems clumsy, but perhaps it is my best bet. I suppose that would allow me to define `topReview()` as `hasOneThrough(Review, TopReview)`.

Feel free to correct me if I'm on the wrong track.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With belongsToMany relationship

```php
class Title extends Model
{
    public function reviews()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Review::class);
    }

    public function topReview()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Review::class, 'top_reviews', 'title_id', 'review_id');
    }
}
```

Anyways you can skip that `top_reviews` table and just save `top_review_id` into your `titles` table and I think that's more efficient

Comment: I suppose I should append `->first()` since `belongsToMany()` will return a Collection? Also the 3rd and 4th arguments seem to be reversed.

As explained above I prefer not to have `top_review_id` in the  `titles` table, because it creates a foreign key cycle.

Answer (score 0):

Depend on you requirement
You one only one top reviews so I think you should Has One Through but if you want to have multi top reviewer on 1 title you should use Many To Many.

- [Has One Through](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#has-one-through)
  I will remove title_id if i use it

```
top_reviews:
  - id
  - review_id (fk, unique)
```

```
class Title extends Model {
    public function topReview() { 
        return $this->hasOneThrough(TopReview::Class, Review::class);
    }

}
```

- [Many To Many](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

```
top_reviews:
  - id
  - title_id (fk, unique)
  - review_id (fk, unique)
```

```
class Title extends Model
{
    public function topReview()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Review::class, 'top_reviews', 'title_id', 'review_id');
    }
}
```

but as you describe above. I think I will use has one through.

Comment: Using `hasOneThrough` how do you enforce that there won't be two top reviews in the database that belong to the same title (since you've removed the `title_id` from `top_reviews`)?

Comment: Ah sorry for my bad english xd. you can keep it both. if you want to enforce from db.

Comment: but how to you know topReview. by vote or ????
also sorry i'm not native speaker

Comment: No worries. Can you explain what's effectively the difference between doing that and `belongsToMany(Review::class, 'top_reviews', 'title_id', 'review_id')->first()`, because the latter will save me the pointless `TopReview` class?

Comment: but for now you can use have one throught. it mean that 1 Reviewer is for only 1 title. and 1 title only has 1 top reviewer.

Comment: if use used belong to many. it mean that your 1 reviewer is belong to 1 title. but 1 title might have many top reviewer.

Comment: but as your design. I think in the further if you want to have many top review that still fine. you just and topReviews() for Belong to Many & topReview() for top 1 Review.